# Update all rows in MySQL where DATETIME has passed

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

What I'm trying to achieve is a scheduled release for articles. I need to write a PHP script that changes a (MySQL) field on every row where a DATETIME column value has passed.

For example: I have a column named `release` that is the type of `DATETIME`. Say the `release` on row X is `2017-03-10 21:48:52`. The time now is `2017-03-10 22:01:34`. That means the time on the field `release` on row X has passed. That means I wish to update a field on this row.

How can I create a `WHERE` statement that finds every row with a passed time.

I think this should be very simple but after a while of searching I couldn't find an answer that would work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple comparison operator and [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function:

```
// releases is your table name
// release_date is your field
UPDATE releases WHERE release_date < NOW()
```

It will update all fields that have `release_date` less than (before) current date and time.

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly the way I wanted! I didn't think you could compare the values so simply. I'm somewhat new to MySQL